# Java JPanel Drawing rectangle drawRect(); what to do next, or which component of Java will suit better?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have drawn a rectangle using a JPanel
My main objective is to store my Requirement Engineering chapter into a JPanel or a JFrame

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class RequirementEngineering extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent();
        g.drawRect(10,10,60,60);
            g2.drawString("Feasibility study", 20, 20); //rectangle is my main objective, I will look after the string later
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
    }
}
```

how do I display the JPanel? I know, JApplet doesn't require a main method, but how do we represent JPanel in main() method?
I have this doubt for long, and other posts are confusing me further, Could I have a direct question
My main question being "How to add JFrame to JPanel" pertaining my current coding
thanks in advance

Comment: JPanel is a contrainer which can also be added as a component in Applet or Frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see if you need to use a Window based app, you can do as:

```
JPanel customPanel = new RequirementEngineering();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("my window");
frame.getContentPane().add(customPanel );
frame.setSize(300,200);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If you need in Applet,

```
public class JAppletExample extends JApplet {
  public void init() {
    Container content = getContentPane();
    JPanel customPanel = new RequirementEngineering();
    content.add(customPanel );
  }
```

And you can run it using appletViewer or in any Web Browser such as IE.

Comment: Could I know what is happening when we are polymorphing RequirementEngineering() to JPanel class?   Edited to add: does it override anything?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

See you have extended JPanel. So your class object is also instance of JPanel as you have inherited.

And I used the different ways to show the UI such as as an Applet or a window.

Do you have any more question about this?

Comment: JFrame frame = new JFrame (); is already initializing the JFrame, but what does frame.getContentPane() do? does it change visibility of a frame? Or add panel into the frame?

Comment: could you please visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

Comment: thanks so much bro, Could I comment here if I got any doubt? thanks for kind help

Comment: watch some step by step java tutorials on youtube

Comment: sure novice. But for more question, better to start a chat. It's recommended by stackoverflow.

Comment: JPanel is a component?

Comment: Yes, Plz see the hiererchy in the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html